# Reload Webview when onMessage callback setting state

Tags: react-native

I am using React native Webview to load my web app. I am posting message from my web app using `window.postMessage` and I have implemented onMessage callback

```
render(){
   return <View>
     <Text>{this.state.messageFromWebview}</Text>
     <WebView onMessage={this.onWebViewMessage} source={{uri: webAppUri}} />
   </View>;
}
```

In `onWebViewMessage` function, in doing

```
onWebViewMessage=(event)=>{
   this.setState({
    messageFromWebview: event.nativeEvent.data
   })
}
```

Above code is going into infinite loop. While setting state, Webview rerendering and calling the post message that triggering the setState.

Is there any alternative or am I missing anything here. Is it possible to set the `<Text/>` to the message from the webview without rerendering the Webview.

Comment: Could someone please look in to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the infinite loop is because of calling the event without const request. All you need to do is add const variable before setState. The following code works for me.

```
onWebViewMessage = (event) => {    
  // set const data
  const WishData = event.nativeEvent.data;
  // then excuting setState the constant data here
  this.setState({ 
    messageFromWebview: WishData 
  });
}
```

Comment: actually, I am doing the way you mentioned. Just for the code clarity I am setting `event.nativeEvent.data` straight to state. But still its not working

Comment: Complete your Webview property, InjectedJavaScript require more variable to load successfully i.e  ref={webview => { wv = webview; }}  onLoadEnd={this._onLoadEnd.bind(this)}   javaScriptEnabled={true} and add before export default class somthing like let wv = null;